# Boost lib appears to be missing hpp files?

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

I'm trying to compile a C++ project that requires Boost.  I downloaded the latest build from the web site and copied the appropriate files to the appropriate libs folder (I'm using MinGW). When I compile, I'm get this error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
headers.h:59:29: fatal error: boost/foreach.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I can find a working copy of `foreach.hpp` but I shouldn't have to move code files manually.

**Solution**

I had copied boost to the wrong folder.

Comment: Did you update the Include path?

Comment: g++ -I <path to boost dir> -c *.cpp

Comment: When you say that you copied them to the "appropriate libs folder", which folder would that be?

Comment: The `*.h` files are not Boost files, they look like windows implementation files. My bet is that when you updated your include path to include the boost files, you deleted the include path for your windows header files, or didn't separate the paths correctly.  Can you post what you did to update your include path.

Comment: I didn't do anything to update the include path, I copied the boost libs to C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.5.2\include\boost and the initial errors went away. A search of my hard drive reveals no such files as resource.h, headers.h, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should make sure that your include path is set correctly. Assuming you downloaded Boost 1.47.0 your path should contain the location to your Boost installation up to the `boost_1_47_0` directory, but leaving out the `boost` one, e.g.

```
/path/to/boost/boost_1_47_0
```

and not

```
/path/to/boost/boost_1_47_0/boost
```

Answer (score 20):

I got this error on Ubuntu 12.10 when trying to use boost with a C++ application without the libraries installed:

```
el@apollo:~/foo8/33_parse_file$ g++ -o s s.cpp
s.cpp:3:29: fatal error: boost/foreach.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

From this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  cout << "hi";
}
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 so I installed Boost like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Then on recompile, it works and now I can use boost!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string text = "token  test\tstring";

    char_separator<char> sep(" \t");
    tokenizer<char_separator<char> > tokens(text, sep);
    BOOST_FOREACH(string t, tokens)
    {
        cout << t << "." << endl;
    }
}
```

Prints the three words `token`, `test`, `string`

Comment: I needed `libboost1.48-all-dev` when compiling CGAL SWIG Bindings on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5):

On Fedora and Centos `yum install -y boost` and `yum install -y boost-devel`

Comment: Also helpful for Amazon Linux variants.